# Title Case a Sentence in Javascript--How does this code work?

Tags: javascript, regex

I found the below solution for title-casing a sentence, and am not sure exactly how it works. Can anybody explain to me what the parts between the double asterisks are doing? I understand that *g* extends the replacement to all instances of *\b.* , but what exactly does *\b.* indicate here? And how does this embedded function work? Thanks in advance for any explanation!

```
function titleCase(string){
return string.toLowerCase().replace( **/\b./g, function(a){ 
    return a.toUpperCase()**; 

} );
}
titleCase('this IS THE wOrst string eVeR');
//returns "This Is The Worst String Ever"
```

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter

Comment: `\b` Matches a zero-width word boundary, such as between a letter and a space. (Not to be confused with [\b])

For example, `/\bno/` matches the "no" in "at noon"; `/ly\b/` matches the "ly" in "possibly yesterday". https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\b Matches the position where a word character is not followed or preceeded by another word-character. Special character like a dot (.) matches a single character.
So:

```
/\b./
```

matches t in 'this', i in ' is', etc.

And a function creates a substring with param received from executed regular expression.

Since you used a global match flag, regular expression will be executed six times for the string in your example.

Answer (score 1):

So, what you're looking at right there is the "replace method" for a string. It's going to take your lower cased string (inside the titleCase function), iterate through it & replace anything that you define in the parameters of that replace method. The parameters inside the replace method

```
string.replace(a,b);
```

where "a" is what you're looking to replace, and "b" is what you want to replace "a" with.

Now, in this particular instance, your replace method is utilizing a Regular Expression as its first parameter, and then whatever that Regular Expression identifies, it's being instructed to be replaced with the function! So, replace methods can take strings, regular expressions & functions as parameters.

Now, this Regular Expression, or RegEx/regex, is saying "find me any character (.) at the beginning of a word boundary (\b)." In RegEx terms, a boundary can be any identifier[s] at the beginning or end of a word, for example. (The first answer from Alexander demonstrates this). And the "g" in`/\b./g` is a "global" flag, meaning that the first character beginning a boundary will be selected (replaced), but I want to select EVERY single first character in the entire string, not just the very first instance. So, for example, using the string you've provided, if we were to leave off the "global flag" from your Regular Expression, your titleCase function would only replace & capitalize "this" in your string. We have to be very specific with Regular Expressions, because of their explicit rules.

Now, your second parameter in the replace method (the replacement), is going to be a function to run some type of instruction[s] on the character[s] that we've initially selected with our first parameter (Regular Expression in this case). Your replacement function is pretty self-explanatory, and uses the parameter "a", which just takes the first letter of every word in your titleCase string, and capitalizes that character.

So, the "replace method" in general is really important in terms of how complex we can change things using JavaScript, especially because it iterates for us without the need to run a "for" or "while" loop. You'll begin to understand the importance of this when you start to work on richer applications of JavaScript. Hope this helps to give you a different perspective of how to understand this code.

Just to throw in my 2 cents, I prefer to write this particular function using a "split" method. It's a little longer, but here's my code:

```
 function titleCase(str) {
  var splitLowerStr = str.toLowerCase().split(" ");
  var newArr = splitLowerStr.map(function(x) {
    return x.replace(/^\w/g, function(a) {
      return a.toUpperCase();
    });
  }).join(" ");

  return newArr;
}

titleCase("You gotta PAY tHe TROLL ToLL, to get in tHE BoY's HOLE");
```

I chose to write it like this to make my code declarative & functional, but there's many different ways to accomplish title casing a sentence. My regular expression is a little bit different, but is also more specific in terms of identifying "word" characters, as opposed to just any character. You can find more about this in most online regular expression tutorials. I really like 
http://ryanstutorials.net/regular-expressions-tutorial/

Comment: The weak point is that this algorithm splits on a space. In practice, words can also be separated by other characters, such as a newline, [an em dash without surrounding spaces](http://grammarist.com/grammar/emdash/), and they can appear between all kinds of brackets, ...etc.

Comment: You're correct, there are specific cases where this code would fail, but for the sake of _explaining_ how to achieve the desired result of a (simple) title cased string, the code demonstrates an easy to understand alternative to running a Regex with (dot), which also has issues with attempting to capitalize characters that aren't letters.